# Bootstrap collapsible panel issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I need to dynamically create collapsible panels containing information. From those panels I would like to total the numbers contained in each panel and output it.

This is very much like a shopping cart. I need to let the user delete any panel they want then total the output again.

If I use the code below all works as expected if you click "remove" from top to bottom until the last panel. The last panel always requires two clicks. So if you start at the bottom all panels will require two clicks.

I have tried many variations of stopPropagation thinking this was the issue but to no avail. Any ideas what may be going on?

btw, I do have a jsFiddle file located here, http://jsfiddle.net/zorfox/8x2me991/ However, the remove link does nothing and I have yet to figure out why. That's why I added the entire code below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<script>
    mytotal = 0;
    cart = [{
        name: 'John',
        age: 1
    }, {
        name: 'Mary',
        age: 2
    }, {
        name: 'Mike',
        age: 3
    }, {
        name: 'Sam',
        age: 4
    }, ];

    function cartdelete(name) {
        for (x = 0; x < cart.length; ++x) {
            for (var key in cart[x]) {
                if (cart[x][key] == name) {
                    // alert('found it');
                    cart.splice(x, 1);
                }; //endif
            }; // endfor 
        }; //endfor 
    }; // endfunc

    function deletecart(id, name, link) {
        cartdelete(name);
        mytotal = 0;
        for (x = 0; x < cart.length; x++) {
            mytotal = mytotal + cart[x].age;
        }
        $('#total').text('Cart Count: ' + cart.length + ' You deleted: ' + name  +
            'Total: ' + mytotal);
        $('#' + id).remove();
    };

    $(document).ready(function () {
        // Dynamically create several panels
        for (x = 0; x < cart.length; x++) {
            $("#total").before("<div  id='cart" + x + "'" + "class='panel panel-default' style='width:50%;'>" +
              "<div class='panel-heading' >" +
              "<h4 class='panel-title'>" +
              "<a data-toggle='collapse' data-parent='#accordion' href='#" + x + "'>" +
              " <strong>" + cart[x].name + ' is ' + cart[x].age + 
              " </strong> <span class='caret'></span></a>" +
              "</h4>" +
              "<a class='tmplink pull-right' id='link" + x + "' href='#" + x +
              "' onclick=" + '"' + "deletecart('cart" +
              x + "' , '" + cart[x].name + "')" +
              '"' + "> remove </a>" +
              "</div>" +
              " <div id='" + x + "'" + " class='panel-collapse collapse'>" + "<div class='panel-body'>" +
              "<table id='table " + x + "'" +
              "<tr> <td>" + cart[x].name + "</td><td>" + cart[x].age + "</td></tr>" +
              "</table>" +
              "</div>" +
              "</div>" +
              "</div>");
        }; // end for loop
        for (x = 0; x < cart.length; x++) {
            mytotal = mytotal + cart[x].age;
        }
        $('#total').text('Cart Count: ' + cart.length + ' Total: ' + mytotal);
    }); //end document.ready
</script>

    <style>
        table,
    td {
      border: 1px solid black;
      width: 50%
    }
    .tmplink {
      position: relative;
      top: -15px;
    }
}
    </style>

<body>
<div id="total">
  Cart Count: 0
</div>
<br>

<button onclick="alert('Cart count: ' + cart.length);">Cart Count</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Work fine for me http://jsfiddle.net/8x2me991/1/

Comment: That's odd. I tried updated versions of IE and Chrome. Nothing happens when the "remove" links are clicked. Maybe the whole problem is specific to my PC...I hope not! lol